# Get PHP variable every minute

Tags: javascript, php, flot

I'm using flot realtime charts and I'm having trouble refreshing my values on the chart.
I have a PHP code to fetch a value and store it to a variable but as I came up to learn the PHP code rus before the pnage is displayed on the browser and it only runs again if I refresh the page. 
Is there a way to make that PHP code fetch the value from the file every minute and plot it?

This is my code:

```
<?php
    function act(){
    $filename = "(...)/CS.txt";
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);
    return $contents;
    };
?>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.pureexample.com/js/flot/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.pureexample.com/js/flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.pureexample.com/js/flot/jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>

<!-- CSS -->
<style type="text/css">
    #flotcontainer {
        width: 95%;
        height: 95%;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>

<!-- Javascript -->
<script>
function cs() {
        var val = <?php echo act(); ?>;
        return val;
};

    var data = [];
    var dataset;
    var totalPoints = 50;
    var updateInterval = 1000;
    var now = new Date().getTime();


    function GetData() {
        data.shift();

        while (data.length < totalPoints) {
            var y = cs();
            var temp = [now += updateInterval, y];

            data.push(temp);
        }
    }

    var options = {
        series: {
            lines: {
                show: true,
                lineWidth: 1.2,
                fill: true
            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            tickSize: [2, "second"],
            tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
                var date = new Date(v);

                if (date.getSeconds() % 20 == 0) {
                    var hours = date.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + date.getHours() : date.getHours();
                    var minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
                    var seconds = date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();

                    return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            },
            axisLabel: "Horas",
            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
            axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
            axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
            axisLabelPadding: 10
        },
        yaxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 300,
            tickSize: 5,
            tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
                if (v % 10 == 0) {
                    return v + "";
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            },
            axisLabel: "Número de CS's",
            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
            axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
            axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
            axisLabelPadding: 6
        },
        legend: {
            labelBoxBorderColor: "#fff"
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        GetData();

        dataset = [
             { label: "CS's", data: data }
         ];

        $.plot($("#flotcontainer"), dataset, options);

        function update() {
            GetData();

            $.plot($("#flotcontainer"), dataset, options)
            setTimeout(update, updateInterval);
        }

        update();
    });

</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="flotcontainer"></div>
```

Comment: You can use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for that.

Comment: No there is not way to make php refresh values every minute without reloading the page. But JavaScript can ask php for the value via ajax every minute without reloading the page.

Comment: I read about it, but since I don't know Ajax I can't make it work =\

Comment: You'll have to learn ajax. Jquery makes it simple : [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using jQuery as I can see, let's blend in some Ajax, easily managed with jQuery.
 First put your function `act()` in a separated php file, let's say `act.php` on the same directory, and make it `echo $contents` instead of returning it:

**act.php:**

```
function act(){
$filename = "(...)/CS.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
echo $contents;
};
```

**then on Javascript global scope:**

```
var val; //setting the val into global scope
//this will get the value echoed in act.php every 60000 miliseconds (1 minute) and set it on val variable;
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){ $.get('act.php' function(data){ val = data}}, 60000);
```

**Change this part from your code:**

```
while (data.length < totalPoints) {
  var y = cs();
```

Instead use `var y = val`; We have been setting the values into the global variable 'val' every minute.

---

Whenever you want to stop the page fetching the act.php's output, just use `clearInterval(myInterval)`

---

**Explanation**

- This is an untested code as I don't have flot and never used it, so take it as pseudo code, maybe you'll need to fix some mistake.

Basicly We are using `setInterval()` to call every 60 seconds a anonymous function that does  a jQuery ajax call to act.php through get, and sets its value into the variable "val".

You could also (and I suggest you to) define the function, ie: function `fetchAct(){....}`  with all the `$.get....` part inside it and call it later: `setInterval(fetchAct, 60000);`

Be aware to assign the interval into a variable `var myInterval = setInterval(...)` so you can stop it anytime you want with `clearInterval(myInterval);`

**In short**:

- [Learn about `setInterval()` and related timer functions...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/tag/JavaScript%20timers)
- [Learn about (jQuery) ajax Calls.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [(Optional): Learn about jQuery's ajax Shorthand Methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/)